# Trying to install rbenv in dockerfile not working

Tags: docker, dockerfile, rbenv

Here is my dockerfile command:

```
# Install rbenv
RUN git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git /home/jenkins/.rbenv \
    && echo 'export PATH="/home/jenkins/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile \
    && git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git /home/jenkins/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build \
    && echo 'export PATH="/home/jenkins/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile \
    && echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.profile \
    && . ~/.profile \
    && rbenv install -v 2.2.3 \
    && rbenv global 2.2.3 \
    && echo $PATH

# Install Sass
RUN . ~/.profile \
    && rbenv versions \
    && gem env home \
    && gem update --system \
    && gem install sass --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

When the `Install Sass` part runs, I keep getting the error of `rbenv not found`. The `echo $PATH` piece doesn't show rbenv apart of the path, so I know that's the issue, just unsure on how to its not working.

Docker version is `v1.11.0`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the full path of `rbenv`, try using

`RUN /bin/bash -c "source ~/.profile"`

to make sure it uses bash to source the environment variables.

You can also use the `ENV` command to make sure all the build statements have access to the environment variables you set, e.g., `ENV PATH /path/to/bin/folder:$PATH`